# How to use jsonb_set to change the value in jsonb

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have jsonb look like this

```json
[{"resultId": "MIDP", "resultValue": "9.3"}, {"resultId": "RBCHistogram", "resultValue": "AAAAA"}]
```

i want to change the resultValue to value1 if the resultid = RBCHistogram.

```sql
        select jsonb_set(macres.test_result, '{0,resultValue}','"ABC"') into v_results
        WHERE v_results ->> 'resultId' = 'RBCHistogram';
```

It returns null value

Answer (score 0):

select jsonb_set(macres.test_result, '{1,resultValue}','"0123"') into v_results;

this is an array, i need to put where the index of the array. thanks guys